# SSL Requests Stop working after a while

Tags: apache, ssl

I have Apache 2.4.2, OpenSSL/1.0.1c, on Windows Web Server 2008 R2 (64 bits)

After 12 hours of heavier load, the SSL requests stopped working/being answered. However if you requested the same page via http instead of https, it worked fine. 
Restarting the Apache server fixes this, for a while. Again after a few hours of traffic, the https requests stopped working again.
I checked the logs, and nothing notable, the mod_ssl entries just...

The site is called only by client developed with Delphi 2007 (CodeGear user-agent). Delphi client use THTTPRIO for sending HTTPS request to SOAP.

Any ideas?

**httpd.conf**

```
AcceptFilter http none
# AcceptFilter https none # (try to uncomment, but ssl stop work)
EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off
```

**httpd-ssl.conf**

```
Listen 443
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:logs/ssl.scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  600
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.76:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/"
ServerName secure.mysite.com:443

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +SSLv3 
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/secure.mysite.com.cer  
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/secure.mysite.com.rsa.key 

SSLVerifyClient none
SSLProxyEngine off

BrowserMatch ".*CodeGear.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0 

LogLevel trace6
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/secure_mysite_com/%Y-%m-%d-error.log 86400"
CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/secure_mysite_com/%Y-%m-%d-access.log 86400" combined


<directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/">
   Options FollowSymLinks Includes
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</directory>

# CGI #
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/CodeGearSOAP_EXE/">
    SetHandler cgi-script
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

TRACE LOG OF ONE SOAP REQUEST

**access.log**

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [27/Sep/2013:18:44:45 +0200] "POST /CodeGearSOAP_EXE/soap.exe HTTP/1.1" 200 4882 "-" "CodeGear SOAP 1.3"
```

**error.log**

```
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:info] [pid 1304:tid 1848] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] AH01964: Connection to child 141 established (server secure.mysite.com:443)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace2] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_rand.c(123): Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1841): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Handshake: start
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1849): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Loop: before/accept initialization
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 11/11 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a0] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 157/157 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152ae] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_socache_shmcb.c(512): AH00835: socache_shmcb_retrieve (0x35 -> subcache 21)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_socache_shmcb.c(836): AH00849: match at idx=0, data=0
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_socache_shmcb.c(523): AH00836: leaving socache_shmcb_retrieve successfully
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace2] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1697): Inter-Process Session Cache: request=GET status=FOUND id=356A6FAB37A0E2729FBEEFAB028CA5C57F799A7F024CD6F037FAB7C9EB6C5010 (session reuse)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1960): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername secure.mysite.com found
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1849): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 read client hello A
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1849): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write server hello A
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1849): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1849): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 write finished A
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1849): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 flush data
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a3] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 1/1 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a8] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a3] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 48/48 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a8] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1849): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Loop: SSLv3 read finished A
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1845): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1890): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1, Cipher: AES128-SHA (128/128 bits)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a3] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 544/544 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a8] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace5] [pid 1304:tid 1848] protocol.c(625):     [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Request received from client: POST /soap/SOAP.exe HTTP/1.1
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [setenvif:trace2] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_setenvif.c(623): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Setting nokeepalive
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [setenvif:trace2] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_setenvif.c(623): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Setting ssl-unclean-shutdown
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [setenvif:trace2] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_setenvif.c(623): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Setting downgrade-1.0
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [setenvif:trace2] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_setenvif.c(623): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Setting force-response-1.0
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_kernel.c(236): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 141 (server secure.mysite.com:443)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(300): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Headers received from client:
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   MIME-Version: 1.0
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   SOAPAction: \\"urn:SoapServerIntf-ISoapServer#SoapCommand\\"
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIME_boundaryB0R9532143182121
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   User-Agent: CodeGear SOAP 1.3
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Host: secure.mysite.com
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content-Length: 4672
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Connection: Keep-Alive
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Cache-Control: no-cache
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_request.c(303): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Cookie: SS_STRINGHELINGUA=IT; __utma=10233637.1711321739.1377762381.1377762381.1377765561.2; __utmz=10233637.1377762381.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_authz_core.c(808): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] request.c(225): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /soap/SOAP.exe
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [authz_core:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] mod_authz_core.c(808): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] request.c(225): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /soap/ISoapServer
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 5/5 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a3] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.307377 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1989): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] OpenSSL: read 4704/4704 bytes from BIO#126bbf0 [mem: 80152a8] (BIO dump follows)
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [cgi:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] util_script.c(519): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Headers from script 'SOAP.exe':
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [cgi:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] util_script.c(522): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Status: 200 OK
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [cgi:trace1] [pid 1304:tid 1848] util_script.c(597): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Status line from script 'SOAP.exe': Status
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [cgi:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] util_script.c(522): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content-Version: MIME-Version: 1.0
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [cgi:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] util_script.c(522): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIME_boundaryB0R9532143182121; start="<http://www.borland.com/rootpart.xml>"
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [cgi:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] util_script.c(522): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content-Length: 4882
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [cgi:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] util_script.c(522): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content:
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [http:trace3] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_filters.c(960): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] Response sent with status 200, headers:
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [http:trace5] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_filters.c(969): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Date: Fri, 27 Sep 2013 16:44:45 GMT
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [http:trace5] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_filters.c(972): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Server: Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_filters.c(804): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content-Version: MIME-Version: 1.0
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_filters.c(804): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content: 
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_filters.c(804): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content-Length: 4882
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_filters.c(804): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Connection: close
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [http:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] http_filters.c(804): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395]   Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIME_boundaryB0R9532143182121; start=\\"<http://www.borland.com/rootpart.xml>\\"
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [ssl:trace4] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(1439): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] coalesce: have 0 bytes, adding 319 more
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.400977 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.432177 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.478978 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.478978 2013] [core:trace6] [pid 1304:tid 1848] core_filters.c(527): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[Fri Sep 27 18:44:45.478978 2013] [ssl:debug] [pid 1304:tid 1848] ssl_engine_io.c(984): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:20395] AH01999: Connection closed to child 141 with unclean shutdown (server secure.mysite.com:443)
```

Comment: I removed the delphi tag, as your question has absolutely nothing to do with Delphi (or programming in general). Please use only tags that actually apply to the question you're asking. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

upgrade Apache to 2.4.3+

configurations added:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
EnableSendfile off
EnableMMAP off
```